# Vertical alignment on text not aligning properly

Tags: c#, wpf

If you run this code, you'll see that the 6 is aligned in the border correctly horizontally, but vertically, its too low by one pixel:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Border Height="46" Width="46" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
            <TextBlock Text="6" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  />
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Now the one pixel may not seem like much, even though it seems off to my eye, but now check out this code instead. Now it's very much obvious, and I'm actually trying to use a larger font size. Now it's about 3 pixels too low.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Border Height="46" Width="46" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
            <TextBlock Text="6" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="50" />
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Any ideas? I know I can hack it into the correct position by using a negative top margin... but...

Comment: It's down to the definition of the font. For example, add the attribute `FontFamily="Courier New"`, and it will now look like it is too high.

Comment: @Richardissimo - You beat me to it. SledgeHammer - yes this is dependent on Fonts design. If you dont set any FontFamily - WPF default is Segoe UI

Comment: @Richardissimo So nothing can be done except a negative top margin? Seems like either the TextBlock or the Border is calculating incorrectly, but then again, if I take off all the alignments, now the 6 is waayy off...

Answer (score 1):

Use padding

```
  <Grid>
        <Border Height="46" Width="46" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
             <TextBlock Text="6" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="50" Padding="0 0 0 5"/>
        </Border>
  </Grid>
```